# Three column layout using CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am trying to do a 3-column layout and was wondering why the blue (right) column wraps around. This works fine in IE but fails to work in Chrome (30.0.1599.101m)

http://jsfiddle.net/V85JF/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="top">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background:gray;
}
.top
{
    width:225px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
}
.left
{
    width:75px;
    height:200px;
    background:Red;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.center
{
    width:75px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
.right
{
    width:75px;
    height:200px;
    background:Blue;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**

I need the center element to have fluid height. Top should take whatever height center takes.

Comment: what about the heights of other child elements? should their height also changes if the height of the `.center` element changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left` for `.center` and `.right` as well.

For fluid height, keep `min-height:200px` of `.center`.
Try this:

```
.top{overflow:hidden;}
.left,.center,.right{float:left;}
.center{min-height:220px;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/V85JF/7/)

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question, I need the center to have fluid height.

Comment: But top won't extend if center grows in height fluidly, right? because all are floating?

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V85JF/4/)

Html

```
<body>
<div class="top">
    <div class="left">
    </div><div class="center">
    </div><div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:gray;
}
.top
{
    width:225px;
    height:auto;
    background:black;
}
.left
{
    width:75px;
    height:200px;
    background:Red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.center
{
    width:75px;
    height:570px;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
}
.right
{
    width:75px;
    height:200px;
    background:Blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This Layout is Fluid

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V85JF/6/)

CSS

```
body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background:gray;
}
.top
{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
}
.left
{
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    background:Red;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.center
{
    width:60%;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.right
{
    width:20%
    height:200px;
    background:Blue;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can't have percentage widths, I need to have fixed widths. I use scss so I can do remainder space calculations.